# Text over a image slideshow - jQuery cycle2

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-cycle2

I'm using jquery cycle2 plugin for the slideshow. Now i'm facing a challenge. I'm able to make the slideshow with the use of that plugin but the thing is i want to write some text on top of the image and the text needs to appeared only for that particular image. But if I use make the slideshow div position relative and the text div position absolute using css nothing's happening.

Code HTML :

```
<div class="offset1 span12 cycle-slideshow">
    <img src="assets/img/1.jpg">
        <div id="text1">
            <strong>A</strong><span>lpha</span>
        </div>
    <img src="assets/img/2.jpg">
    <img src="assets/img/3.jpg">
</div>
```

Code CSS :

```
.cycle-slideshow {
position: relative; 
}
#text1 {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
}
```

Anyhelp will be very much pleased.

Comment: give the site url it ll be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this may help u.if stil this not working means ur slide div may contain large z-index than ur text div

```
.cycle-slideshow {
position: relative; 
z-index:1;

}
#text1 {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 200px; 
    color:#fff;
    z-index:2;

}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TDSFF/

Answer (score 1):

Follow the steps [described in the documentation](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/overlay.php):

1. Add a div with the class `.cycle-overlay` inside the cycle slideshow

   - Add CSS rules
2. Add the `data-cycle-title` and `data-cycle-desc` attributes on the slides. Leave empty if necessary.

[Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/salman/q6hp7/)